# Testing sorting algorithms with different sizes of number sets

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting

I have a C code which implements firstly a **bubble sort algorithm**, and then **AVL Sort** to different sizes of number sets. I have 4 different .txt file which include different sizes of number sets (10000 - 100000 - 1000000 - 10000000). When I try both algorithms with more little number sets, or even trying them on only one number set, both algorithms work fine and give true outputs. But when I call them sequentially in the `main` function, the console program is being interrupted and stopping to work. Here are my calls in the main function;

```
int main()
{

    test("10000.txt", 10000);
    test("100000.txt", 100000);
    test("1000000.txt", 1000000);
    test("10000000.txt", 10000000);


    return 0;
}
```

Here, what `test()` function doing is, reading all of the lines from **.txt** files and both inserting them into a **AVL Tree** and in an **unsorted array**. Then **AVL Sort** and **Bubble Sort** algorithms works, the elapsed time is recorded and printed on the console. Even though I comment out the codes about AVL Sort, and only run Bubble Sort, it is being interrupted when I call the `test()` function sequentially in the main. Here is my bubble sort function;

```
void bubblesort(unsigned long long *arr, int n)
{

    int i, j;
    unsigned long long temp = 0;

    for(i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {

       for(j = 0; j<n-i-1; j++)
       {

            if( arr[j] > arr[j+1])
            {
                temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j+1];
                arr[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is the console output when I call test() sequentially, as you can see only the first .txt file with 10000 elements tested and then program got interrupted;

[image: This is the console output when I call test() sequentially, as you can see only the first .txt file with 10000 elements tested and then program got interrupted.]

So, are there anyone who can explain me what the problem is here ? Thanks for help.

Edit: For the ones who wanted me to share test() function, I removed the lines about AVL Tree and simplified it with only showing the Bubble Sort part. It is simply not crushing when the bubble sort is alone, it sorts 10.000 elements in 0 seconds, 100.000 elements in 44 seconds, but when it comes to 1.000.000 elements, it simply waits too long, maybe more than 10 minutes but still can't give any output. Is that normal for a bubble sort to spend too much time on sorting that number of elements?

```
void test(char *fname, int n)
{
    time_t start, end;
    FILE *fp;
    int i = 0;
    unsigned long long number;
    unsigned long long *unsorted = (unsigned long long  *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned long long)*n);

    fp = fopen(fname, "r+");
    for(i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        fscanf(fp, "%llu\n", &number);
        unsorted[i] = number;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    time(&start);
    bubblesort(unsorted, n);
    time(&end);
    printf("bubblesort function's time spent is %ld second for %d number of elements.\n", (end - start), n);
    free(unsorted);    
}
```

Comment: You forgot to post the code for the `test()` function.

Comment: It is a really long code, should I share it ?

Comment: How are you creating the arrays?  If you use a VLA (variable length array), you've probably blown your stack.  If you use `malloc()` et al, you should be OK; if you use a global variable, or even a static variable in the function, you should be OK (on this count, anyway).

Comment: @OzanYurtsever If it's really long, try to reduce it to the minimum code that still has the problem.

Comment: Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]), where 'complete' is as important as 'minimal'.  That usually means modifying (a copy of) your program, sometimes quite seriously.  But yes, you should show enough of your code to make it easy to reproduce your problem.  It isn't obvious that the problem is in the function you do show.  For example, can you do without the AVL tree sort if you think the problem is in the bubble sort, or vice versa?

Comment: @mnistic, I posted its long form, now I am going to try reducing it.

Comment: Why are you opening the file in update mode?  You aren't writing the results to the input file, are you?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, No, the sorted results only stored in arrays and didn't even printed. There is no updating for .txt files, they will remain same.The main purpose is calculating the sorting times and comparing them.

Comment: The current code does not compile (missing definition of `number`). Please test and make sure the code still has the same problem before updating.

Comment: @mnistic, When I simplified the function, I deleted some necessary variable declarations as mistake. Now I fixed it

Comment: Have you actually tested with the simplified function? Is it still crashing?

Comment: @mnistic Add checks after mallocing and fopen.

Comment: @mnistic, Actually when I tried it again, it is simply not crushing when the bubble sort is alone, it sorts 10.000 elements in 0 seconds, 100.000 elements in 44 seconds, but when it comes to 1.000.000 elements, it simply waits too long, maybe more than 10 minutes but still can't give any output. Is that normal for a bubble sort to spend too much time on sorting that number of elements ?

Comment: When I use the code, it seems to work.  It takes less than a second on 10,000 random numbers; it took about 17 seconds on 100,000 random numbers.  I'm still running the 1,000,000 sort — it's likely to take most of half an hour.  I won't be timing the 10M sort; that's too long.  (Using GCC 8.2.0 on a MacBook Pro running macOS 10.14.1 Mojave.)  So, as before, the problem is not self-evidently in the code you show.  Note that Bubble Sort is an O(N²) algorithm, so when you multiply the input by 10, it takes about 100 times as long to execute.

Comment: @OzanYurtsever Yes bubble sort is pretty terrible: https://vinayakgarg.wordpress.com/2011/10/25/time-comparison-of-quick-sort-insertion-sort-and-bubble-sort/

Comment: @JonathanLeffler,  I think I understand where I am wrong. I am not freeing my tree after testing one .txt file.

Comment: Thanks all, I am going to write a function to free my tree and will share the results from here.

Comment: OK; that would probably explain it.  The tree will use considerably more space than an array will.  It also demonstrates that you should be error checking your file open operations and memory allocation operations.